# Preloading all content of the app on branded launch screen

Tags: java, android, xml

So my app is 80% done, but because it haves many pictures, multiple fragments with 20+ buttons per fragment, and all other heavy stuff it lags a little bit.

Until now I solved that problem by putting loading dialog when users clicks on activity, but that's not long term fix..

I wonder, can somehow whole content of the app load on app start, that is, on branded launch screen? And by that way that when user clicks on activity there's no delays and lags.

Comment: I don't think that would be an adequate solution even if it was possible, since Android can clear memory when apps are minimized, you still need to handle the cases that your pre-load is missing. It sounds like many large images are your issue. Have you tried launching activities and fragments as usual, but loading images in a background thread?

Comment: Perhaps. But then a lot would depend on how the data is going to be fetched, the source of the data, the size of the data, the user's internet speed and how it is going to be stored would matter a great deal. Considering the above, there is a risk that the _branded screen_ ending up taking an awful lot of time which might result in a substantial number of users (_perhaps_) uninstalling the application.

Comment: It's not due to the image. For example, when user clicks on first button that my app show, it goes to activity that has 6 tabs and every tab has 20+ buttons which are LinearLayouts (need to have them because of tablerows, etc). That takes 3-4 seconds to load, which is causing skipping frames and therefore, lag.. Picures load just fine

Comment: @DaxHR: Use the _Monitors_ option / tab under the _Android Monitor_ in Android Studio, find out the exact reason that causes the lag and start fixing it / them. Your question is rather theoretic and the problem area could be anywhere.

Comment: Memory is ok, no more that 80MB, but processor is up to 50% when launching those heavy activities.. Tested on Xperia Z1